# What is the difference between the differential and derivative of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

So from my understanding the derivative of a function is a function that will map a vector to a matrix so if the function is $f:\mathbb{R}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^1$ the derivative is a function $f':\mathbb{R}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{1 \times1}$ . For a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^1$ the derivative is $f':\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{1 \times2}$. For the general case if $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ then the derivative is $f':\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m \times{n}}$

Now for the differential, it is a function that is a linear transformation so it takes a vector to another vector, but I'm confused exactly what the range vector space is. Lets use an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.

$$f(x,y) = (x^2-y^2, xy)$$
The derivative is
$$Df=
\begin{bmatrix}
2x & -2y \\
y & x \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And the differential is

$$df=
\begin{bmatrix}
2x & -2y \\
y & x \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
dx \\
dy\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2xdx -2ydy\\
ydx+xdy\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

so my intuition of the differential is $$f(x+\Delta{x}, y+\Delta{y})-f(x,y)$$

if we use the example above and let $(x,y) = (1,2)$, $\Delta{x}=0.1$, and $\Delta{y = 0.1}$ you get
$$f(1,2) = (-3,2)$$
$$f(x+\Delta{x}, y+\Delta{y})=(-3.2,2.31)$$
$$f(x+\Delta{x}, y+\Delta{y})-f(x,y) = (-0.2, 0.31)$$
And if you use the differential but replace $dx$ and $dy$ with $\Delta{x}$ and $\Delta{y}$ you get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2x\Delta{x} -2y\Delta{y}\\
y\Delta{x}+x\Delta{y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and plugging everything in you get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2*1*0.1 -2*2*0.1\\
2*0.1+1*0.1\\
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
-0.2\\
0.3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Which is a little different, but that's because the "differential" (using $\Delta$ instead of $dx$) is a linear approximation, and as $\Delta$ gets smaller they will be closer. Also I believe vector $(dx,dy)$ can point in any direction. My problem is when we change $\Delta$ to $dx$ doesn't that basically mean taking the limit of $\Delta{x}$ as $\Delta{x}$ goes to $0$, and wouldn't that make the differential the $0$ vector everywhere? I'm self taught so I hope this is even close to making sense, also sorry if I abused terms or notation.